# Copy/paste code optimized with offset?

Tags: vba, excel

First I need to apologize for the title, I am having trouble finding a relevant one!

I'm having trouble optimizing the following code.
The goal of this macro is to import values from one workbook to another.

Workbook1 is the source and Workbook2 the destination.

What I would like to do is avoid having a repeated code, especially because the length of the source report can change everyday, but the values I need to extract are always offset by 87 rows (ex: After looking at C30 I need to go to C117, C204, C291 ... Same for C7, C86 and F45 which is the first set of values I need to export, next one being C94, C173, F132 And so on).

```
lMaxRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

If wbkWorkbook1.Worksheets("SC_Server").Range("C30") > 0 Then
wbkWorkbook2.Worksheets("StaffCaf").Range("B" & lMaxRows + 1) = _
wbkWorkbook1.Worksheets("SC_Server").Range("C7")

wbkWorkbook2.Worksheets("StaffCaf").Range("F" & lMaxRows + 1) = _
wbkWorkbook1.Worksheets("SC_Server").Range("C86")

wbkWorkbook2.Worksheets("StaffCaf").Range("N" & lMaxRows + 1) = _
wbkWorkbook1.Worksheets("SC_Server").Range("F45")
End If

If wbkWorkbook1.Worksheets("SC_Server").Range("C117") > 0 Then
wbkWorkbook2.Worksheets("StaffCaf").Range("B" & lMaxRows + 1) = _
wbkWorkbook1.Worksheets("SC_Server").Range("C94")

wbkWorkbook2.Worksheets("StaffCaf").Range("F" & lMaxRows + 1) = _
wbkWorkbook1.Worksheets("SC_Server").Range("C173")

wbkWorkbook2.Worksheets("StaffCaf").Range("N" & lMaxRows + 1) = _
wbkWorkbook1.Worksheets("SC_Server").Range("F132")
```

I hope my explanation is clear :)

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the Declarations to your list.

You can use a loop and tell it how many to skip at a time.  The `Step 87` tells the loop to jump 87 every time.

I also put your worksheets into variable and used a `With` block to save typing.

From there it is just math to get the correct cells.

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim i As Long


Set ws1 = wbkWorkbook1.Worksheets("SC_Server")
Set ws2 = wbkWorkbook2.Worksheets("StaffCaf")
With ws1
    For i = 30 To .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row Step 87
        lMaxRows = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

        If .Range("C" & i) > 0 Then
            ws2.Range("B" & lMaxRows + 1) = .Range("C" & i - 23)
            ws2.Range("F" & lMaxRows + 1) = .Range("C" & i + 56)
            ws2.Range("N" & lMaxRows + 1) = .Range("F" & i + 15)
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: Thank you so much Scott, works wonderfully ! One question, what do you mean by "Add declarations to your list" ?

Comment: Move the Dim statements to where you have declared your other variables.

Comment: Ok I see :) Thank you again